# jQuery animating back to original position

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate

I've got a site i'm working on that has a few absolutelty positioned divs that I need to resize on clicking, these will then fill the container that the divs are in. The question is how do I get them on toggle to go back to the original position (top, left) which is different for each.

```
$(".work-item .toggle").toggle(function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({ height: '430', width: '930', top: '0', left: '0' }, 750);
    },
    function() {
        var pos         = $(this).parent();
        var position    = pos.position();      

        $(this).parent().animate({ height: '150', width: '200', top: position.top, left: position.left }, 750);
    });
```

Tried the above but it's getting the new position not the original.

Thanks in Advance.

PVS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can store the position when the page first loads using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and use it later, like this:

```
$(".work-item .toggle").each(function() {
  $.data(this, 'position', $(this).parent().position());
}).toggle(function() {
  $(this).parent().animate({ height: '430', width: '930', top: '0', left: '0' }, 750);
}, function() {
  var position = $.data(this, 'position');
  $(this).parent().animate({ height: '150', width: '200', top: position.top, left: position.left }, 750);
});
```

This stores the [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) for each element's parent just before you bind, then uses that when animating back later.